# How to capture console.error with Karma unit test runner?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner

Karma will capture any messages written to `console.log` but not anything written to `console.error`. I understand that karma uses log4js under the hood.

Is there any way to configure karma to capture `console.error`?

Answer (score 12):

Karma does capture `console.error` (see https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/415d0257c23ff7be07e240648bfff0bdefa9b0b6/client/karma.js#L70)

Make sure you set config `client.captureConsole: true` and use the latest Karma.

Answer (score 4):

You could capture the `console.error` as described in this [blog post](http://blog.berniesumption.com/software/make-karma-jasmine-tests-fail-on-console-errors/)

```
describe('TestSuite', function() {
  var oldError = console.error;
  beforeEach(function() {
    console.error = function(message) {
      throw new Error(message);
    };
  });
  return afterEach(function() {
    return console.error = oldError;
  });

  it('should fail', function() {
    console.error("Oops!")
  });
```